# How can I extract features from fMRI network connectivity analysis (FSL nets)?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a set of 37 fMRI images from mice which are divided into 4 classes (different drug doses applied). My task is to train classifiers (SVM etc.) on this dataset. Of course feature extraction is a very important step.

I'm now investigating a feature extraction method based on FLS nets (network connectivity analysis). I did not myself perform this step, I just got the FSL net results. The results can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/heepk2ensvhamvh/AADgT4nPXI7lKzSLd4xZPNYEa?dl=0

There are 140 files representing (small) regions. I have thresholded each file with a threshold of 0.95, i.e. I only kept voxels in each file which are above this threshold. In the end 37 files survived thresholding giving a total of 799 voxels. In the fMRI image each voxel is a time series of 350. I could now take the correlation between all the voxels but this would give just too much features.

How could the feature size decreased further? I think the number of voxels from the netwrok connectivity analysis must be reduced, perhaps just increasing threshold... An other approach could be to find clusters and then representing each cluster as one vector (averaging time series) and then taking the correlation between the vectors (clusters).